# How can we do Paging in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to do paging in grid view that actually binds from a list. Can any one please help me out? 
Actually as the data is extracted from a list , am getting "null" while data it is being populated to the next page. So i would like to know whether the users here faced such a criteria.

Method used to bind the grid is as below,

```
private void bindGrid()
 {
if (items != null)
{
foreach (var item in items)
{
name.Add(new organisationName(((System.Xml.XmlElement)((System.Xml.XmlNode[])(item))[7]).InnerText,
((System.Xml.XmlElement)((System.Xml.XmlNode[])(item))[3]).InnerText));
}
searchResultGrid.DataSource = name;
searchResultGrid.DataBind();

}

}
```

and in the PageIndexChanging event of gridview i used the below code

```
protected void searchResultGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
bindGrid();
searchResultGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
searchResultGrid.DataBind();

}
```

aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="searchResultGrid" runat="server" PageSize="20" Width="60%" AllowPaging="true"
Visible="False" OnPageIndexChanging="searchResultGrid_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="searchResultGrid_RowDataBound"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="searchResultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="searchResultGrid_RowCommand">
<Columns>

</Columns>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
No Data Found</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "**This question does not show any research effort;** it is unclear or not useful." Consider reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and the related links it provides.

Comment: [This Google Search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=Paging+in+gridview) shows some promising results. The article @Saravanan links to in his answer below is the first search result.

Comment: @Anjana: Your edit doesn't really help.  Are you getting an error message, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Hope you all found the updated question

Comment: Did u face the same problem if you make your data source a Data Table instead of list??

Comment: please put the `aspx` of the `gridview` and some code if possible.

Comment: Please find the updated Question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Paging is a inbuilt feature of GridView control and the solution to bring them are really strait forward.

Go through this article to get better idea on paging. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Mr Saravanan. Actually as the data is extracted from a list , am getting "null" while data it is being populated to the next page. So i would like to know whether the users here faced such a criteria. Thanks again .

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of two ways to page your Gridview.

1-use the built in paging in asp.net gridview control through (`AllowPaging`).

2-make your own paging way.

for more about this issue:

-[GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Paging and Sorting the GridView's Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx)

-[Grid View Paging and Sorting](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1249-Grid-View-Paging-Sorting.aspx)

-[GridView Custom Paging](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewCustomPaging.aspx)

you can  search ,and get more explanations about this feature either from articles or through a lot of videos in youtube.

Comment: Please find the updated Question. Thanks